# Difference between Gibbs sampling and variational Bayes inference

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, feature-engineering, probability, sampling

After reading blogs and books, I came to the conclusion that Gibbs sampling and variation Bayes are methods for estimating or inference of posterior. The below link is described but it's difficult to interpret.

https://users.ics.aalto.fi/alexilin/papers/step10.pdf

It can be a sense that both methods are most probably used in a probabilistic model. Practically Gibbs sampling is very slow compared to the variational base.

Can anyone explain how this happens? It would be interesting if one will brief me about it.

Comment: It would be good if you give a citation about "variational base" to a paper or wikipedia.